# What is the Microsoft GraphServiceClient v5 Replacement for AppendSegmentToUrl

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, graphserviceclient

While investigating an upgrade of my C# use of Microsoft GraphServiceClient v4 to v5 I was looking at the usage I have of the [chats: getallMessages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chats-getallmessages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) for which I need to be able to append the "model" query string parameter this format:

```
GET /users/{id | user-principal-name}/chats/getAllMessages?model=A
```

In v4 it would look like:

```
string userGuidString = ...
GraphServiceClient gsc = ...
var results = await new UserChatsCollectionRequestBuilder(
   gsc.Users[userGuidString].Chats.GetAllMessages().AppendSegmentToRequestUrl("?model=A")
   , gsc.Request().GetAsync();
```

Checking the [MS upgrade guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md) I see only one mention of the AppendSegmentToRequestUrl which was only how to stop using it for the $count piece and use a built in method.

The best I can come up with for v5 is to deal with it myself by using the Uri class.

```
string userGuidString = ...
GraphServiceClient gsc = ...
var results = await new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.Chats.GetAllMessages.GetAllMessagesRequestBuilder(
   new Uri(gsc.Users[userGuidString].Chats.GetAllMessages.ToGetRequestInformation().URI, "?model=A").ToString()
   , gsc.RequestAdapter).GetAsync();
```

Sure this works, but since they didn't call out this issue in the upgrade guide it seems like I must be missing how to do this in the v5 syntax. Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, it's bug in SDK v5. Time to time, the similar problem is found for another endpoint and when you create a new ticket, they will fix it. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/new/choose Then you should be able to use var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Chats.GetAllMessages.GetAsync(rc =>{rc.QueryParameters.Model = "A";});

Comment: Thanks @user2250152, I have filed bug https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1972